# 502 - The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, http-status-code-502

Similar question: [Error: Server Error The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.(GCP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744880/error-server-error-the-server-encountered-a-temporary-error-and-could-not-compl)

I'm using the Google Cloud Platform for my website and ran into an issue.

The above question is similar to my issue except this issue isn't persistent for me. I have the website https://fixly.is, if I refresh any page a couple of times, any one of the assets loaded for the page isn't fetched and I get a 502 error. When I refresh it again immediately, it loads it just fine.

The response I get for the asset request is this:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

I've attached a screenshot as well.
[image]

I also haven't configured a load balancer.

Is this issue because I haven't configured a Load Balancer?
Can someone tell me why I'm getting this issue?

I'm adding a log for when an asset isn't fetched.
[image]

Comment: 502 often means your application crashed and did not respond to the upstream frontend. Most applications/web servers log error details.

Comment: Please also update your question|tags to reflect the specific compute service that you're using. Google's Frontend -- like every other Google service -- is a distributed system and it's probable that you're hitting a difference Frontend instance on your refreshes and that these don't have the relevant file cached. Did you deploy|update shortly before observing this behavior? Has the problem resolved after some time (minutes)? Your files appear to not all include `cache-control` directives. For static content you should ensure that there are `cache-control` headers so that proxies can cache it.

Comment: have you checked your logging, for errors and alerts regarding the issue you are encountering? I was able to access your website a moment ago. Verify that the network endpoint group is configured with the correct IP:Port or FQDN:Port for your external backend. If you are using FQDN, make sure that it is resolvable through Google Public DNS. You can verify that the FQDN is resolvable through Google Public DNS using [these steps](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) or the [web interface directly](https://dns.google/).

Comment: @JohnHanley I added the Log file. But there aren't any details here.

Comment: @DazWilkin No, we deployed it a while ago, and the issue can ever since. The problem isn't resolved after some time.

Comment: Those logs do not match your 502 error.

Comment: @JohnHanley Oh sorry about that let me fetch the correct logs.

Comment: @IsmailFarooq does your site still encounter 502 errors? You can check this [troubleshooting guide] (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs#troubleshooting_general_connectivity_issues) from Google. Monitor health check traffic reaches your backend VMs. If you already configured your load balancer, *the lack of successful health check log entries does not mean that health check traffic is not reaching your backends. It might mean that the backend's initial health state has not yet changed from unhealthy to a different state.*